# The Intersection of a plane and a surface is nonempty?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus

First let's think about a simple analog in 2D. Suppose that there is a function y=h(x) that is increasing and a line y=-x, then "obviously" there is an intersection between $y=h(x)$ and $y=-x$.

Now Consider a four dimensional space $\mathbb R^4$.

Let $P$ be a 2 dimensional plane in $\mathbb R^4$, such that for all $a,b\in\mathbb R^2$, the point $(a,b,b,a)$ is in the plane $P$.

---

$f(x,y,z,w)$ is a $\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R$ continuous function. $f$ is monotonically increasing in the direction of $x$ and $w$ and decreasing in the direction of $y$ and direction $z$. You could assume that $\lim_{y\to +\infty}f=\lim_{z\to +\infty}f$

Let $S=\{(x,y,z,w):f(x,y,z,w)=0\}$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb R^4$.

> Is it possible to show that the intersection of $P$ and $S$ is nonempty? If not, what simple assumption is needed?

Basically  it is enough to show that $f(a,b,b,a)=0$ for some $a,b$

I guess we could start by changing the definition of coordinates. Make a new coordinate system like $(e_2,e_3,e_4,e_1).$

So in the new system $P=\{b,b,a,a\}$.

In the new system $f$ becomes $f(y,z,w,x)$. $f$ is decreasing in the first two coordinates and increasing in the last two.

Now we group the first two coordinates and the last two coordinates: $((e_2,e_3),(e_4,e_1))$

$P=\{(c,d):c,d\in\mathbb R^2, c_1=c_2,d_1=d_2\}$.

$f$ becomes $f(t,v)$ where $t,v\in\mathbb R^2$. $f$ is increasing in $v$ but decreasing in $t$, so we might consider the equivalent expression v=g(t) such that $f(t,g(t))=0$? As $t$ increases, $g(t)$ decreases.

Now we want to show that $f(c,d)=0$ or $d=g(c)$ for some $c,d$ and $c_1=c_2$, $d_1=d_2$. Which seems obvious by fixed point theorem?

Comment: P seems to be a point in the 4D space. A plane in 3D is defined by a  single equation with 3 variables - I would expect a plane to be the intersection of two volumes defined in the 4D.

Comment: @Moti Hi, I refined the expression!